# improving crtp error message when using same function name in base and derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

When using crtp is there a nice way to improve the error message (maybe using static_assert in some way) that the compiler generates when you have a member function with the same name in both the base and derived classes?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class Ignore> 
struct ignore { typedef T type; };

template<class T, class I>
using Ignore = typename ignore<T, I>::type;

template<class T> 
struct A 
{
    template<class IgnoredParam = void>
    auto foo() -> decltype(declval<Ignore<T*, IgnoredParam>>()->foo()) 
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->foo();
    }     
};

struct B : public A<B> 
{
    //int foo() { return 42; };
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    auto i = b.foo();
    cout << i << '\n';
}
```

On gcc 4.7.1 the error message isn't particularly bad for the above example, you just have to skip the part apart exceeding the maximum template recursion limit, but it can be a bit worse when interacting with more deeply nested hierarchies.

This is more of an annoyance than a problem, normally I delegate to a foo_impl instead, but I was wondering if anyone had a way to improve the error message you receive when compiling the above.

Comment: The issue here is that you are defining that the return type of `foo()` be equal to itself!

Maybe you are not communicating your ultimate goal here.  Are you trying to force the user to specify a `foo` method within `B`?

Also, please show us the `foo_impl` solution; maybe that will help us to understand.

Comment: .. in other words, you are satisfied with the fact that this is an error?  And you just hope for better error messages?